# Python Azure BloblClient UTF-16 issue

Tags: python, azure, csv, azure-blob-storage, utf-16

I would like to pump data from a stream into a csv file save in Azure ADLS Gen2 Blob container.
The encoding should be UTF-16-LE to be able to open it with Excel properly.
If I use UTF8 without BOM then my code works properly, but in case of UTF-16 the result is a mess.
I use StringIO and csv module to convert incoming data into CSV formatted strings. The data I upload may have the max of 1mio rows (for Excel compatibility).

I have also tried blobclient.append_block() which added BOM at the beginning of every chunk in the CSV file, so let's say in every 1000. line there was a BOM.

Do you have any idea how to read list of lists from a stream and upload it into Azure Blob as an excel compatible csv file? (I found that Excel handles only UTF16 properly for the data what I have.)

Azure blob version: '12.14.1'

The result looks like this with UTF-16:
(UTF-16-LE adds NUL endians which is hardly readable in notepad++, opening in Excel is even worse)

```
"string";"integer";"float﻿"2.";2;3.0
﻿"4.";4;6.0
﻿"6.";6;9.0
＊⋾㠀⸀∀㬀㠀㬀㄀㈀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㄀　⸀∀㬀㄀　㬀㄀㔀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㄀㈀⸀∀㬀㄀㈀㬀㄀㠀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㄀㐀⸀∀㬀㄀㐀㬀㈀㄀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㄀㘀⸀∀㬀㄀㘀㬀㈀㐀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㄀㠀⸀∀㬀㄀㠀㬀㈀㜀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㈀　⸀∀㬀㈀　㬀㌀　⸀　ഀ＀⋾㈀㈀⸀∀㬀㈀㈀㬀㌀㌀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㈀㐀⸀∀㬀㈀㐀㬀㌀㘀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㈀㘀⸀∀㬀㈀㘀㬀㌀㤀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㈀㠀⸀∀㬀㈀㠀㬀㐀㈀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㌀　⸀∀㬀㌀　㬀㐀㔀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㌀㈀⸀∀㬀㌀㈀㬀㐀㠀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㌀㐀⸀∀㬀㌀㐀㬀㔀㄀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㌀㘀⸀∀㬀㌀㘀㬀㔀㐀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㌀㠀⸀∀㬀㌀㠀㬀㔀㜀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㐀　⸀∀㬀㐀　㬀㘀　⸀　ഀ＀⋾㐀㈀⸀∀㬀㐀㈀㬀㘀㌀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㐀㐀⸀∀㬀㐀㐀㬀㘀㘀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㐀㘀⸀∀㬀㐀㘀㬀㘀㤀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㐀㠀⸀∀㬀㐀㠀㬀㜀㈀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㔀　⸀∀㬀㔀　㬀㜀㔀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㔀㈀⸀∀㬀㔀㈀㬀㜀㠀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㔀㐀⸀∀㬀㔀㐀㬀㠀㄀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㔀㘀⸀∀㬀㔀㘀㬀㠀㐀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㔀㠀⸀∀㬀㔀㠀㬀㠀㜀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㘀　⸀∀㬀㘀　㬀㤀　⸀　ഀ＀⋾㘀㈀⸀∀㬀㘀㈀㬀㤀㌀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㘀㐀⸀∀㬀㘀㐀㬀㤀㘀⸀　ഀ＀⋾㘀㘀⸀∀㬀㘀㘀㬀㤀㤀⸀　ഀ਀﻿"68.";68;102.0
﻿"70.";70;105.0
﻿"72.";72;108.0
﻿"74.";74;111.0
﻿"76.";76;114.0
﻿"78.";78;117.0
﻿"80.";80;120.0
﻿"82.";82;123.0
﻿"84.";84;126.0
﻿"86.";86;129.0
﻿"88.";88;132.0
﻿"90.";90;135.0
﻿"92.";92;138.0
﻿"94.";94;141.0
﻿"96.";96;144.0
﻿"98.";98;147.0
```

The reference code that I modified is from [MS learning site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-python)

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from uuid import uuid4

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContentSettings, BlobBlock #, ContainerClient

class MyDialect(csv.Dialect):
    """ CSV dialect compatible with Synapse DP SQL COPY INTO command """
    delimiter      = ';'
    doublequote    = True
    lineterminator = '\r\n'
    quotechar      = '"'
    quoting        = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
    escapechar     = "/"
    
    
class FakeReader:
    def __init__(self, chunk_size = 2):
        self.chunk_size = 2
        self.data_set = [[str(i)+".", i, i * 1.5] for i in range(100)]
    
    def header(self):
        return [["string", "integer", "float"]]
    
    def readChunk(self):
        ix = 0
        while True:
            data = self.data_set[ix : ix + self.chunk_size]
            ix += self.chunk_size
            yield data
            
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        print("closing the input stream...")

        

def getBloblClient(account_name, account_key, container_name,
                   max_chunk_get_size = 4 * 1024 * 1024, max_single_get_size = 4 * 1024 * 1024, 
                   file_relative_path = "data.csv"):
    blob_url = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(blob_url, 
                                            credential = account_key,
                                            max_chunk_get_size = max_chunk_get_size,
                                            max_single_get_size = max_single_get_size
                                           )
    return blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container = container_name, blob = file_relative_path)
            

def upload_blocks(blob_client, chunk_size : int = 2, block_size: int = 1024*1024, encoding = "UTF-8"):
    
    csv.register_dialect("mydialect", MyDialect)
    
    # memory csv stream as data pipe between 
    stream = io.StringIO()
    csv_writer = csv.writer(stream, dialect = "mydialect")
    
    record_cnt = 0
    bytes_moved = 0
    block_id_list = []
    first_chunk = True
    
    with FakeReader(chunk_size = 2) as reader:
        for chunk in reader.readChunk():
            record_cnt += len(chunk)
            if first_chunk:
                chunk = reader.header() + chunk
                first_chunk = False
            
            # convert the records into CSV rows
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()
            csv_writer.writerows(chunk)

            # append the csv rows from the stream object to blob storage csv file
            stream.seek(0)
            buffer = stream.read(block_size)
            
            if not buffer:
                break
            bytes_moved += len(buffer)
            
            # append to blob stage
            block_id = uuid4().hex
            block_id_list.append(BlobBlock(block_id = block_id))

            blob_client.stage_block(block_id = block_id, 
                                    data = buffer, 
                                    length = len(buffer), 
                                    encoding = encoding)

        blob_client.commit_block_list(block_id_list)
    
    return bytes_moved, record_cnt



account_name   = "account-name"
container_name = "container-name"
account_key    = "your-account-key"

blob_client = getBloblClient(account_name, account_key, container_name)
upload_blocks(blob_client, encoding = "UTF-16-LE")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The result looks like this with UTF-16: (UTF-16-LE adds NUL endians which is hardly readable in notepad++, opening in Excel is even worse)

You are using a UTF-8 encoding-compatible CSV dialect in your code. But you must specifically manage the encoding because you wish to submit the data as UTF-16-LE. Before uploading the CSV data to **`Azure Blob Storage`**, you may encode it as UTF-16-LE using Python's encode function.

Two-byte characters are included in **`UTF-16 data`**, and additional care must be taken to provide suitable encoding and endianness.

You can use the below-modified code:

**Code:**

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
import io
from uuid import uuid4

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContentSettings, BlobBlock #, ContainerClient

class MyDialect(csv.Dialect):
    """ CSV dialect compatible with Synapse DP SQL COPY INTO command """
    delimiter      = ';'
    doublequote    = True
    lineterminator = '\r\n'
    quotechar      = '"'
    quoting        = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
    escapechar     = "/"
    
    
class FakeReader:
    def __init__(self, chunk_size = 2):
        self.chunk_size = 2
        self.data_set = [[str(i)+".", i, i * 1.5] for i in range(100)]
    
    def header(self):
        return [["string", "integer", "float"]]
    
    def readChunk(self):
        ix = 0
        while True:
            data = self.data_set[ix : ix + self.chunk_size]
            ix += self.chunk_size
            yield data
            
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        print("closing the input stream...")

        

def getBloblClient(account_name, account_key, container_name,
                   max_chunk_get_size = 4 * 1024 * 1024, max_single_get_size = 4 * 1024 * 1024, 
                   file_relative_path = "data.csv"):
    blob_url = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(blob_url, 
                                            credential = account_key,
                                            max_chunk_get_size = max_chunk_get_size,
                                            max_single_get_size = max_single_get_size
                                           )
    return blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container = container_name, blob = file_relative_path)
            

def upload_blocks(blob_client, chunk_size : int = 2, block_size: int = 1024*1024):
    
    csv.register_dialect("mydialect", MyDialect)
    
    # memory csv stream as data pipe between 
    stream = io.StringIO()
    csv_writer = csv.writer(stream, dialect = "mydialect")
    
    record_cnt = 0
    bytes_moved = 0
    block_id_list = []
    first_chunk = True
    
    with FakeReader(chunk_size=2) as reader:
        for chunk in reader.readChunk():
            record_cnt += len(chunk)
            if first_chunk:
                chunk = reader.header() + chunk
                first_chunk = False

            # convert the records into CSV rows
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()
            csv_writer.writerows(chunk)

            # Append the csv rows from the stream object to blob storage csv file
            stream.seek(0)
            buffer = stream.read(block_size)

            if not buffer:
                break
            bytes_moved += len(buffer)

            # Encode the data as UTF-16-LE
            utf16_buffer = buffer.encode("utf-16le")

            # Append to blob storage
            block_id = uuid4().hex
            block_id_list.append(BlobBlock(block_id=block_id))

            blob_client.stage_block(block_id=block_id, data=utf16_buffer, length=len(utf16_buffer))

    blob_client.commit_block_list(block_id_list)

    return bytes_moved, record_cnt


account_name   = "xxxxx"
container_name = "xxxxx"
account_key    = "xxxxxx"

blob_client = getBloblClient(account_name, account_key, container_name)
upload_blocks(blob_client, encoding = "UTF-16-LE")
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I could produce the file but unfortunately it had no encoding information embedded. Tried to change the encoding to utf-16-le or just utf-16 but had the same result. May I ask you to try to add "autosúčiastky" as a fake field to the input data and check the result?

Comment: I have added the LE BOM to first utf16_buffer and it worked! :-)
```if first_chunk:
                utf16_buffer = b"\xff\xfe" + utf16_buffer
```